# Unable to change image size in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

My image is unable to resize. Firstly I have put the background in the container widget. After that, I have put the logo image in the center widget using Image.assets. The main problem is that the size of the image is resizing according to the height and width. Currently, I am coding in the flutter framework using dart language.

I am doing coding in Android Studio.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: new AssetImage("assets/imgs/home_bg.png"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
              ),
            ),
            new Center(
              child: Image.asset("assets/imgs/home_logo.png",height: 300,width:300,),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

No error messages are showing. Then also the image is not resizing.

Answer (score 4):

```
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
          child: Image.network(
              "https://th.thgim.com/opinion/op-ed/article22695424.ece/alternates/FREE_300/9thscience"),
        ),
      ))
```

Comment: Remember to specify both width and height, else it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like-

```
new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: <Widget>[
    new Expanded(child: new Image.asset(
        "assets/imgs/home_logo.png",height: 300,width:300,
    ),

    ),
  ]
)
```

Comment: what's the Text(cover.name) ??

Comment: Sorry, i removed it

Comment: ohk...but still it is not resizing

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
    height: 20.0,
    width: 20.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
    child: Image.asset(
      'assets/Like@3x.png',
    ),
  );
```

Comment: what's the meaning  of @3x ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try wrapping the Image in a Flexible located in a Column wich is wrapped in a Container with the dimensions you need

Comment: Unfortunatly i have no access to my PC at the moment. Maybe i can add it later, sorry :/

Comment: The other solution seems to be much smoother anyway

Comment: Ohk...Thanks but please share the code because I am a beginner in flutter

Comment: and also using Flexible widget image is not displaying on the screen

Comment: Yes you have to wrap the Image itself in a Container again. This worked fine for me, if i remember it correctly